# Referenciar elemento DOM em Jquery de outra maneira

Tags: jquery

Olá, veja estas linhas de código:

```
 <div id="divn4" align="center"><i style="">Nunca, nunca enviamos span.</i></div>
```

Então, se eu quisesse referenciar o itálico ali, para aplicar alguma função nele, sem precisar colocar uma id, ou classe, no Jquery como posso fazer?
Penso em algo como:

```
$("#divn4[i]").text("teste");
```

Resumindo, seria algo como acontece no CSS, onde você pode criar um seletor não necessariamente usando uma ID ou Classe..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `i` é uma tag de HTML da mesma maneira que `p` ou `div`, e por isso um seletor CSS válido, então a solução é:

```
$("#divn4 i").text("teste");
```

Se quiseres mudar todos os itálicos podes mesmo usar `$("i")`

Exemplo:

```js
$("#divn4 i").text('Texto dentro do "i" aqui.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divn4" align="center">Texto fora do "i" aqui. <i style="">Nunca, nunca enviamos span.</i></div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, não tinha essa ideia que era era da mesma maneira a especificidade aplicada lá no CSS, também era no javascript(jquery), grato parceiro, até mais.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Os seletores do jQuery (e do JS puro com `querySelector` e `querySelectorAll`) são os mesmos do CSS, salvo uma ou outra extensão.